# How do you take content in a div that is within a form and put it into a database along with other form data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, form-data

I have searched exhaustively on ways to accomplish this task. I am having issues in turning content within a div into a variable that is able to be processed into a php statement. I have tried using AjaxForm I have tried AJax.

Here is my form code which is under the title "library.php". Here I have a div with the ID "input". I Am trying to get the data in this div which will either be the option "Public" or "Private". I will then proceed to use the button create to submit the data to the database.php

```
<form method="post" action="library.php" id="form3">
 <a id="libOptPP" class="select">                       
  **<div id="input" class="input" name="Privacy">               
  </div>**
  <div id="libOptPP2" class="select-options">
   <ul> 
    <li id="pub" value="1"><span>Public</span> (logo) </li>
    <li id="priv" value="2" class="selected"><span>Private</span></li>
   </ul>                    
  </div>
 </a>
 <div class="libOptCS">
  <span class="bbCT"> 
   <button type="submit" name="create"> Create </button>
  </span>
 </div>
</form>
```

Here is the script that lies within the head of the Library.php where I will try and use ajax to send the variable "privacy" to the Database.php. This variable will contain the text of the div that is stated in the previous block of code. This will either be the option "Public" or "Private". Instead of using the ID name of the div I went ahead and used the classes to select it which is ".select .input".

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function main() { 
  $("create").click(function() {    

  var privacy = $(.select .input).text();                       
  .ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ../../database/database.php,
    data: "privacy="+privacy,
    dataType: "html",   
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
    }   
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Here is the php code for entering the form data into my database. Once we click the create button as stated in the previous code this will activate the transferring of data into its proper table and subsequent rows.

```
if (isset($_POST["create"])) {
 $Privacy = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['privacy']);
 $ETH = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['ETH']);
 $Email_Phone_Number = $_SESSION['Email_Phone_Number'];

 if ($Privacy === "Public") {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO library (Title, Privacy, Bio, User_iD)
         VALUES ('$ETH', '$Privacy', 'testbio', (SELECT User_iD FROM logstart WHERE Email_Phone_Number='$Email_Phone_Number'))";
         mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 }
if ($Privacy === "Private") {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO library (Title, Privacy, Bio, User_iD)
        VALUES ('$ETH', '$Privacy', 'testbio', (SELECT User_iD FROM logstart WHERE Email_Phone_Number='$Email_Phone_Number'))";
         mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 }
 if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
  echo "YES!";
  } else {
  echo "No!";
  }
}
```

Somewhere along The variable is not being identified. When I press the "create" button A pop up of "unidentified Index: privacy" is created. In other words $_POST['privacy'] does not contain the data that I need it to, which should be Public or Private so that I can identify that and further use the rest of the code.

Comment: Don't know PHP but...why aren't you using an input control - whether hidden, text or textarea?  Also, you're binding to the click event of the create button, but it's a submit button and you're not calling preventDefault so maybe the form is being submitted before your code runs?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is posting back the normal way rather than using ajax because of two things:

1) You aren't binding the click event to the button properly - your selector is looking for elements like `<create>` which of course don't exist.

2) Once that's solved, you forgot to prevent the default postback behaviour of the button. You can sort this either using markup or code. Markup is simpler:

```
<button id="create" type="button" name="create"> Create </button>
```

Note the `id` attribute to uniquely identify the button, and the the `type="button"` attribute - unless the type is "submit", then it won't cause the form to do a normal postback. Then your event handler should be:

```
$("#create").click(function() {
```

Note the `#` which tells jQuery to look for an element with the id "create".

Another problem: Your PHP contains a logical error. You are calling mysqli_query multiple times for the same query, instead of checking the result of the earlier query. Your if statements to do with the Privacy value also seem to be redundant - you don't change the query as a result. This is how you need to do it:

```
if (isset($_POST["create"])) {
 $Privacy = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['privacy']);
 $ETH = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['ETH']);
 $Email_Phone_Number = $_SESSION['Email_Phone_Number'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO library (Title, Privacy, Bio, User_iD)
         VALUES ('$ETH', '$Privacy', 'testbio', (SELECT User_iD FROM logstart WHERE Email_Phone_Number='$Email_Phone_Number'))";
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql); //return the result of the query for checking

 if ($result === true) {
  echo "YES!";
  } else {
  echo "No!";
  }
}
```

See also my comment above re SQL Injection vulnerabilities, which is not directly related to your question but does require your urgent attention.

**EDIT**
There are also a number of other issues with your script, including syntax errors, which are likely to be stopping it from working. Here's a fixed / improved version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#create").click(function() {

    var privacy = $(".select .input").text();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../../database/database.php",
      data: { "privacy": privacy },
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

There were missing speech marks round variables, manual creation of data string (risking encoding issues, which jQuery can take care of for you if you pass it an object), closure which doesn't need a name, and unnecessary use of `async: false` (it just locks the browser for no good reason).

---

Comment: This has helped but I am still getting issues of an unidentified index for Privacy. In other words my problem still persist in not being able to give value to this php variable.

Comment: actually looking more closely at your script there are a number of obvious problems with your code including syntax errors, which will mean the script just is not running, and therefore is probably still posting back the normal way. If you check your browser's console you'll probably see them when you run the code. I'll edit the question in a moment with a fixed version